# Zen Barcode is not rendering in ssrs report while loading report in browser

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SQL server 2008 express.
I have created one RDL file and i have used zen barcode to display barcode in my Report.
But when i deploys it to server then it is not displaying on browser.

I have also tried with sql server 2008 full version but still its not working.

But, I have another system in that system sql server 2008 full version is installed. And in that machine it is working fine.

I am attaching both system snap.[image: Working in one system]

[image: Not Working]

Please give me solution.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi that happen because your server need that font to working so you have to add this in Control Panel - Fonts.

Comment: Which Fonts ? As per i know when we are using Zen Barcode then we dont required to install any font..

Comment: Hi Which fonts i need to install ? I have another machin in which i didn't install ant font even though its working fine in that machine